# (Javascript) - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, ajax, attributes

The following code is generating the error in Title: I'm sure it is something related to **this.getAttribute('data-name')**, since if I remove it, everything works fine.

```
var id = item.registrationID;
var nome = item.registrationName;

document.getElementById('divPaziente').innerHTML += "<button class='button button-block button-positive' id='"+id+"' data-name='"+nome+"' onclick='redi(this.id, this.getAttribute('data-name'));'>"+nome+' '+cognome+' - '+id_referenza_paziente+"</button>";

window.redi = function(id, nome)
{
  alert(id);
  alert(nome);
  localStorage.setItem("id", id);
}
```

Comment: You need to escape your quotes

Comment: try escaping the quotes `this.getAttribute(\'data-name\')`

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the ' around data-name , because the string will be considered to end at "getAttribute('".

```
'redi(this.id, this.getAttribute('data-name'));'
^                                ^
|                                |
+-Start of string.               +- End of string (escape it..)
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution:

from:

```
redi(this.id, this.getAttribute('data-name'));
```

to:

```
"' onclick=\"redi(this.id, this.getAttribute('data-name'));\">"
```

```js
var item = {registrationID: 1, registrationName: 'name'};
var cognome = "cognome";
var id_referenza_paziente = "id_referenza_paziente";
var id = item.registrationID;
var nome = item.registrationName;

document.getElementById('divPaziente').innerHTML +=
        "<button class='button button-block button-positive' id='" + id + "' data-name='"+ nome +
        "' onclick=\"redi(this.id, this.getAttribute('data-name'));\">" +
        // "' onclick='redi(this.id, this.dataset.name);'>" +
        nome +' '+ cognome + ' - ' + id_referenza_paziente + "</button>";

window.redi = function(id, nome)
{
    alert(id);
    alert(nome);
    localStorage.setItem("id", id);
}
```

```html
<div id="divPaziente"></div>
```

Second solution (based on [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)):

from:

```
redi(this.id, this.getAttribute('data-name'));
```

to:

```
"' onclick='redi(this.id, this.dataset.name);'>"
```

```js
var item = {registrationID: 1, registrationName: 'name'};
var cognome = "cognome";
var id_referenza_paziente = "id_referenza_paziente";
var id = item.registrationID;
var nome = item.registrationName;

document.getElementById('divPaziente').innerHTML +=
        "<button class='button button-block button-positive' id='" + id + "' data-name='"+ nome +
        "' onclick='redi(this.id, this.dataset.name);'>" +
        nome +' '+ cognome + ' - ' + id_referenza_paziente + "</button>";

window.redi = function(id, nome)
{
    alert(id);
    alert(nome);
    localStorage.setItem("id", id);
}
```

```html
<div id="divPaziente"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved using `this.getAttribute(&quot;data-name&quot;)`.